# What is the excel keyboard shortcut alternative for ALT+SHIFT+ARROWS

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

ALT+SHIFT+ARROWS in Word or Powerpoint, helps in moving a particular paragraph or line up or down. What is the corresponding shortcut in excel.

I am not looking at cut, copy, paste or mouse drag or macro solutions. Is there a shortcut, as simple as that.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the one linked referred to rows in excel, while I require might be a cell or a row. Also, the one referred is looking for a easy way, while I am looking for a specific shortcut. Unless you have the exact answer I am looking for, please don't use your reputation to put this question on hold.

Comment: Everyone here is trying to help you for free. If there are reasons this question is not a duplicate, clarify your question. It wasn't even clear to me what you were asking for, until someone else pointed it our. So, if you want people to help you, you might want to help yourself by no not getting an attitude with those helping you.

Comment: @Firee Takes more than just my vote to close it (regardless of how much rep I have). :)   As CharlieRB points out, you may want to edit your question to clarify exactly what you're looking for.  But as-is your _exact_ question is "Is there a hotkey to do X", and the _exact_ answer is "no" (as two people have pointed out already).  If you want an alternative way to do what you are trying to accomplish (beyond just trying to identify if a hotkey exists or not), then I believe what I linked to is correct/good info.  Anyhow, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to be one. Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-HP010073848.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ditto, to Wutnaut's answer, for excel 2010.  No shortcuts from what I can tell: 
[Microsoft Shortcut Reference for Excel2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-2010-HP010342494.aspx)

Comment: CharlieRB's answer underscores an ambiguity in the question: what is it that you are trying to move? I assumed it was a selection of cells, and that you were interested in moving a selection of cells by one cell in any direction. CharlieRB, rightly points out that there are "inserts" that can be moved as well.

Comment: Did you read the questions? Do you know about the ALT+SHIFT+ARROWS shortcut and how it works in powerpoint & word, if not then please don't go by some charlie's word on this.

Comment: @Firee Please don't be insulted. Consider that I did answer the question with what you were seeking: There are no shortcuts that will move the contents of cells as described in my previous comment. However, I standby the comment above: Your question doesn't clearly state what you are trying to move. This is important information because there are several things that can be "moved" in Excel, AND not one of them is synonymous with what is being moved in Word/Powerpoint, in excel they are different objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut needed. To move an object (text box, line, shape, picture, etc.) in Excel, you simple select it and use the arrow keys. There is no need to hold an alternate key.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants to shift a line/row up and down, similar to how (as they say) Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down works in Word.  Highlighting a row and hitting "UP" doesn't move the current row up one, it just changes which cell is selected. :)

Comment: You know, I didn't read it that way. Now that I have read it again, I see what you are saying. I was thinking "it can't be that simple of an answer". LOL Thanks.